# Using Gym in python to simulate a robotic arm for Reinforcement ML

Tags: python

I am trying to create an environment in GYM to simulate a robotic arm I have designed. None of the supplied environments for robotic arms actuate their movement as I want to, so I think i need to create an agent and environment. Do i do this on a CAD design software and then implement it as an environment somehow or any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please include what you have tried.

Comment: At the moment i haven't tried anything i am trying figure out more so where to start